# Flask request.form.getlist() doesn't get checkbox values if they're not checked

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

So I have a table with several columns. There us functionality to add more rows as needed. One of the cells is a checkbox with a name of `cardio-nurse`

On the route in Flask I am doing the following

```
cardio_nurse = request.form.getlist('cardio-nurse')
return str(cardio_nurse)
```

If I have 4 rows and only check 2 of the boxes, I get:

```
['true', 'true']
```

However I thought I would get the following is the 1st and 3rd were not checked:

```
[None, 'true', None, 'true']
```

Any suggestions how to get the every checkbox value and default to `None` if it's not checked?

One way around it would be to set the value of a hidden field upon checking/unchecking but this seems more of a bodge than a solution in JS

stackoverflow is a sesspit of negativity

Comment: Please show the HTML and complete route as a [mcve]. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid js manipulation and all the other stuff you described, another approach would be to store your choices in a python list and compare the chosen values ​​with this list, then bring out the differences:

```
all_choices = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
cardio_nurse = request.form.getlist('cardio-nurse') 
cardio_nurse = cardio_nurse * (len(all_choices) - len(cardio_nurse))
checked = ['true' if i in cardio_nurse else None for i, _ in zip(all_choices, cardio_nurse)]
```